# Is there a client for Google Talk, for Mac, that allows phone calls?

Tags: macos, google-talk

I'm having no luck finding a client for Google Talk that is both for Mac (OS X) and that allows phone calls (not just chatting with other Google Talk users).  If I leave the browser page open to gmail, it will ring when I receive a call to my Google Voice number, and I can call out from my Google Voice number, but I don't want to use the browser.

Is there any sort of client, for Mac, that will allow calls through Google Talk?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you taken a look at this application, [Voice Mac](http://mrgeckosmedia.com/applications/info/VoiceMac)?

I haven't tried it myself yet but it seems outdated, last update was in Sept. 2011.

> VoiceMac is the first Google Voice client for the Mac. Send multiple SMS Messages, send SMS Messages, receive SMS Messages, place calls, look at your call history, receive voicemail, reverse lookup a phone number, and search your contact list in one easy interface. When you receive a SMS Message or Voicemail, you get notifications via Growl and hear sounds that is customizable.
>
> With SIP support you can place calls from your computer using your favorite SIP service and if you link your Google Voice Number with the SIP service, you can place calls with your Google Voice Number from your computer. With the reverse lookup data, you can see who is calling you, even if their number isn't in your contacts list.
>
> With themes, you can customize your SMS Messages look anyway you like with simple HTML or by downloading a theme.
>
> VoiceMac's contacts system is one of the best contacts system around, with support for Address Book and Google Contacts. You can search your contacts just like a Search Engine with speed.
>
> VoiceMac is Open Source at http://opensource.mrgeckosmedia.com/VoiceBase/Mac/Mob.

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of apps that will let you send / receive SMS as well as initiate calls. Receiving calls, however, is a different story. VoiceMac will not ring when someone calls you. It will notify you when they leave a message, but it won't actually ring so that you can answer it.

In the end, I've downloaded the TalkaTone app for my Android phone (http://www.talkatone.com). After logging into my Google account through the TalkaTone app, all phone calls to my Google Voice number will ring on my mobile phone (over a data network, not over mobile minutes). It's not a great connection, but it truly is the only thing I could find (other than leaving GMail open in my browser) that would actually ring when people call my Google Voice number.